# Sum of a random number of identically distributed but dependent random variables?

Tags: pr.probability, asymptotics, limit-theorems

## Background

Let $X_t$ be the continuous time Markov process on the state space {Working, Broken} with failure rate $\alpha$ and repair rate $\beta$.  By elementary calculations [1] 
$$
\begin{align*}
  P\left\{ X_t = \text{Working}\ | \ X_s = \text{Working} \right\} &= p + (1-p) \cdot e^{-(\alpha+\beta)(t-s)} \\
  P\left\{ X_t = \text{Broken}\ | \ X_s = \text{Broken} \right\} &= 1-p + p \cdot e^{-(\alpha+\beta)(t-s)}
\end{align*}
$$
where $p = \frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta}$.

Without loss of generality, we assert that the process has converged to its stationary distribution at time $t = 0$.  (Equivalently, from any start time, let the process run until it is arbitrarily close to stationary, then reset the time origin.)

Let $U$ be the cumulative sojourn Working during an interval $[0,\tau]$ (the process's *uptime*).  Then $U$ is asymptotically normal as $ \tau \rightarrow \infty $, with a mean $\mu_U$ and variance $\sigma^2_U$ that can be calculated from $\alpha$ and $\beta$ [2].

## My conjecture

Suppose we reward the process at rate $g(t)$ if it is Working at time $t \in [0,\tau]$, 
where $g$ is bounded and $F(x) = \frac{1}{\tau} g^{-1}(x)$ is a well-defined cumulative distribution function.  Let $\mu_R$ and $\sigma^2_R$ be the mean and variance of the distribution defined by $F$.

Let $Q$ be the reward accumulated during $[0,\tau]$.  My conjecture is that $Q$ is asymptotically normal as $ \tau \rightarrow \infty $, with mean $\mu_Q$ and variance $\sigma^2_Q$ calculated as
$$
\begin{align*}
  \mu_Q &= \mu_R \mu_U \\
  \sigma^2_Q &\approx \left( \sigma^2_R + \mu_R^2 \right) \sigma^2_U
\end{align*}
$$

**Edit:** Originally conjectured `=' for the calculation of $\sigma^2_Q$ but I'm not so sure now.

The conjecture has empirical support from experiments with the following

- $g(t) = \frac{k}{\tau}\left(\frac{t}{\tau}\right)^{k-1}$ for $k > 1$
- $g(t) = \frac{k}{\tau}\left(1 - \frac{t}{\tau}\right)^{k-1}$ for $k > 1$
- $F$ specifying a uniform distribution
- $F$ specifying a triangular distribution
- $F$ specifying an arcsine distribution
- $F$ specifying a U-quadratic distribution

## What I'm trying

Setting $\delta t = \frac{\tau}{n}$, $t_k = (k-1)\delta t$ and using $1_{t}$ to indicate that $X_t$ is Working at time $t$, we have
$$
  Q = \lim_{\delta t \rightarrow 0} \sum_{k = 1}^{n} g(t_k) \cdot 1_{t_k} \ \delta t
$$

Now suppose that $R$ is distributed according to $F$.  Then choosing $Y$ uniformly from $[0,1]$ and calculating $g(Y\tau)$ is equivalent to sampling $R$ (by the [inverse probability integral transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling)).  So
$$
  Q = \lim_{\delta t \rightarrow 0} \sum_{\ell = 1}^{M} R_{\ell} \ \delta t
$$
where $M = \frac{U}{\delta t}$ and the $R_{\ell}$ are distributed according to $F$.

Thus $Q$ is the sum of a random number of identically distributed but dependent random variables.

## My question

What theorems exist on asymptotic distributions for the sum of a random number of identically distributed but dependent random variables?

(I am aware of [3] for example on the asymptotic distribution for the sum of a random number of independent identically distributed random variables.)

Many thanks in advance.

## References

[1] Nicolas Privault, 2013, *Understanding Markov chains: Examples and applications*, Springer Undergraduate Mathematics Series, vol. IX, Springer, Singapore.

[2] Lajos Takács, 1959, On a sojourn time problem in the theory of stochastic
  processes, *Transactions of the American Mathematical Society*, 93(3), 531--540.

[3] Herbert Robbins, 1948, The asymptotic distribution of the sum of a random number of random variables, *Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society*), 54, 1151-1161.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [*think I have*] proved the calculation for $\mu_Q$ and $\sigma^2_Q$ by applying the [methods I used in a related problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/184280/publishing-an-elementary-proof-of-a-less-general-and-less-useful-version-of-a-cl).

I then [*also think I have*] proved that $Q$ is asymptotically normal (under certain conditions) using the Berry-Esseen theorem derived at [1].

## References

[1] Gutti Jogesh Babu, Malay Ghosh, Kesar Singh, 1978, On rates of convergence to normality for $\phi$-mixing processes, *The Indian Journal of Statistics*, 40(A)(3), 278-293.